# Что не так с размером массива numpy?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

У меня учебное задание нарисовать с помощью *OpenGL* вращающийся по траекториям текст. Не стану приводить всего кода, связанного с отрисовкой сцены, поскольку ошибка в размерности массива. Также в скрипте использую модуль *pygame*.

Есть функция `draw_text(text)`. Она принимает текст как аргумент и создает  текстовую поверхность с помощью модуля *pygame.font*. Далее получает размеры этой поверхности (`width` и `height`) с помощью метода *get_size*. Затем функция проверяет, что ширина поверхности кратна 4. Если не кратна, то увеличивается до ближайшей кратной 4 ширины. После этого функция преобразует поверхность с помощью метода *tostring()* в строку байт и создает массив numpy с помощью метода *frombuffer()*. В конце функция преобразует массив в 3D-массив с размерами `(width, height, 3)` и возвращает его. Для построения сцены 3D-массив в дальнейшем будет использоваться для сохранения текстуры, которая затем будет наложена на 3D-модель и отображена с помощью OpenGL.

Код:

```
# создание текста на поверхности
def draw_text(text):
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)

    # создание поверхности с текстом
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0))

    # получение параметров поверхности с текстом
    width, height = text_surface.get_size()

    # проверка, что ширина кратна 4
    if width % 4 != 0:
        width += 4 - (width % 4)

    # преобразование поверхности с текстом в массив numpy
    image_str = pygame.image.tostring(text_surface, 'RGB', True)
    data = np.frombuffer(image_str, dtype=np.uint8)
    data = np.reshape(data, (width, height, 3))
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2ffa5c8203da> in <module>
     87 
     88     # отрисовка текста
---> 89     draw_text("Hello, World!")
     90 
     91     pygame.display.flip()

<ipython-input-1-2ffa5c8203da> in draw_text(text)
     52     image_str = pygame.image.tostring(text_surface, 'RGB', True)
     53     data = np.frombuffer(image_str, dtype=np.uint8)
---> 54     data = np.reshape(data, (width, height, 3))
     55 
     56     # наложение текстуры на квадрат

<__array_function__ internals> in reshape(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in reshape(a, newshape, order)
    296            [5, 6]])
    297     """
--> 298     return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
    299 
    300 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     55 
     56     try:
---> 57         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     58     except TypeError:
     59         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 11016 into shape (156,24,3)
```

Пытался менять местами `height` и `width`, но не помогло. Просто уведомление `...into shape (156,24,3)` в трейсбэке ошибки преобразуется на `...into shape (24,156,3)`.

Предположил, что параметр `reshape`, равный -1, позволит *numpy* самостоятельно подобрать недостающую размерность массива с учетом указанных размеров других осей. В итоге я поменял строку с функцией `reshape()` на  `data = np.reshape(data, (width, -1, 3))`, но это вывело ошибку `...into shape (156,newaxis,3)`.

Что можно исправить?

Comment: Новые размеры массива должны в произведении равняться старым размерам при reshape, а 156*24*3=11232, а не 11016, 156 вообще стоит брать, тк 11016 не делится нацело на 156

Comment: @Step1709, спасибо за арифметику: на будущее буду такую проверку делать. Но в данном случае это не решает моей задачи, как преобразовать имеющиеся размеры в 3D-формат с добавлением параметра `3` для трехмерности

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, какими должны быть размеры, за исключением параметра 3-полагаю это количество цветов RGB, соответственно произведение длинны и ширины должно равняться 11016/3=3672. Например 51*72=3672, или 102*36=3672, выбирайте из этих величин